# Jquery – Select optgroup in select

Tags: jquery, select, optgroup

I have a select with 2 optgroups. Is there a way to call an function only if an option from the first optgroup is selected and call another function if an option from the second optgroup is selected?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure.

HTML:

```
What is your preferred vacation spot?<br>
<SELECT ID="my_select"> 

<OPTGROUP LABEL="OptGroup One." id="one">        
<OPTION LABEL="Florida">Florida</OPTION>         
<OPTION LABEL="Hawaii">Hawaii</OPTION>         
<OPTION LABEL="Jersey">Jersey Shore</OPTION>    
</OPTGROUP> 

<OPTGROUP LABEL="OptGroup Two" id="two">  
<OPTION LABEL="Paris">Paris</OPTION>  
<OPTION LABEL="London">London</OPTION> 
<OPTION LABEL="Florence">Florence</OPTION>  
</OPTGROUP>

</SELECT>
```

JS:

```
$("#my_select").change(function(){
    var selected = $("option:selected", this);
    if(selected.parent()[0].id == "one"){
        //OptGroup 1, do something here..
    } else if(selected.parent()[0].id == "two"){
        //OptGroup 2, do something here
    }
});
```

**Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pyG2v/**

Comment: Amazing. The code looks so clear and easy but I struggled so much on that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){
  var $option = $('option:selected', this); // get selected option
  var optGroup = $option.closest('optgroup').index(); // get which optgroup
  if(optGroup == 0){
    // first
  }
  else if(optGroup == 1){
    // second
  }
  else{
    // not first or second
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on option you get the Id name of option group.

```js
    var obj = {};
$('select[name=queue]').on('change', function () {
    obj = {};
    var options = $('option:selected', this); //the selected options
    $.each(options, function (index, option) {
        var optgroupIndex = $(option).closest('optgroup').index() //get the index
        var optgroupId = $(option).parent()[0].id //get id
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(optgroupId)) {
            obj[optgroupId].push($(option).val());
        } else {
            obj[optgroupId] = [$(option).val()];
        }
    });
    var textRows = [];
    $.each(obj, function(optgroupId, values){
        textRows.push(optgroupId +": " + values.join(', '));
    });
    $('#demo').html(textRows.join("<br>"));
});
```

```css
 /*Additional*/
select::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-moz-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-o-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-google-ms-scrollbar {display:none;}
select::-khtml-scrollbar {display:none;}
select{height:150px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name='queue' multiple> 
<optgroup label="Frist Queue" id="Frist Queue">
<option value="Person1">Person1</option>         
<option value="Person2">Person2</option>         
<option value="Person3">Person3</option>    
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Second Queue" id="Second Queue">  
<option value="Person1">Person1</option>  
<option value="Person2">Person2</option> 
</optgroup>
</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
```