# Nested selectable option's tree

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I'm trying to make a selectable option's tree like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/s1yr41k3/

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Category 1">
    <option>Sub Category 1</option>
    <option>Sub Category 2</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="Category 2">
    <option>Sub Category 3</option>
    <option>Sub Category 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

but, as you can see, i'm not able to select the main categories because they're just simple labels.

I've been looking for a different solution but unfortunally i didn't find nothing yet.

Comment: what you trying to do??

Comment: I want to be able to select the main category also.

Comment: up to my information & search I think you cannot do that .. but you can get optgroup  data after user selected option like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475003/jquery-select-optgroup-in-select

Comment: how am i supposed to do something like this? how do other people make it? i can't believe it is impossible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565864/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-optgroup

Comment: add an option for each category ... doesn't seem complicated. Or use one of the multitude of select replacement plugins

Comment: Can you provide an example?